# How can I add emoticons to comments?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, emoticons

I'll focus on the blueprint because the execution is easy.
So I think I made some progress with this but I need a way to restrict the addition of HTML by the user because with one `<br />` one can ruin the entire comment section of worse add js.
I made a function that takes the a certain code like

> :e:001

to

`<img id="1" scr="source1.png">`

but its not working because the when I add the image tag I have to transform this comment string to html which enables other html tags the user can add.
How can fix this problem?

Simpler Question: How can I add images but leave the rest of the comment as string?

PS. I'm aiming for images not web emoticon font.

Comment: Not really clear what the question/problem is, but generally you'd first strip away all HTML *before* adding your own.

Comment: @Juhana the question is, how can I add images to text but leave the rest of the text as string or not html safe? Any better option than clearing the HTML before adding the image?

Comment: ヾ(･ω･｀*) - (*´･ω･)ﾉﾞ Anddd... the rest is string..

Comment: @choz I don't understand what you just posted

Comment: Its one kind of emoticon.. And its in comment..

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer rather very simple one, when I make the comment I make it as html and upload it as html then view it as html so the text will stay as string because its still HTML and haven't converted to text then to html back like I did before.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, your image tag is either not all there or you have the syntax wrong. The image tag should look like this : 
   `<img src="LinkToImage">`

Comment: Hi!  Welcome to StackOverflow.  Your answer is more of a comment applied to the question.  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a
Q&A site, where we reserve the answer space for answers. Please check out our
short [tour] when you have a chance.